# Not using router's DNS

Tags: windows-7, router, dns

I ran GRC's "DNS Benchmark" software on my Windows 7 machine, and it says: `System has only ONE (router based) nameserver configured`, which shows up as one of the slower one in the test.

I have already explicitly set both the router and my PC to using Google's DNS servers as described [here](https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/windows-7) and [here](https://store.opendns.com/setup/device/2wire), but DNS Benchmark still says: `System has only ONE [router based] nameserver configured` (even though I have explicitly set the DNS server on the PC) and that it is slow (even though, even if the router's DNS settings were used, it should be using Google's public DNS).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be sure about the running configuration, open a command shell console (cmd) and type:

```
nslookup www.google.com
```

You will see something like this:

```
C:\Users\leandro>nslookup www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.0.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2800:3f0:4002:801::1013
          173.194.42.48
          173.194.42.52
```

The first two lines show you which the actual DNS is being used. In my case 10.0.0.2 is my router. You can also force nslookup to use another server with this command:

```
C:\Users\leandro>nslookup www.google.com ns1.google.com
Server:  ns1.google.com
Address:  216.239.32.10

Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2800:3f0:4003:801::1013
          173.194.42.243
          173.194.42.242
```

This will let you know if GRC test is right about your configuration.